# Custom chunk implementation

Tags: filepond

Is it possible to customize the chunk configuration in Filepond such that the chunk information is provided to the upload server:

- as query parameters instead of headers
- with custom query parameter names instead of `Upload-Length`, `Upload-Name`, and `Upload-Offset`

I am trying to fit Filepond's chunk implementation to a third party upload endpoint that I don't have control over.

I have found the [Advanced configuration](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#advanced) where you provide a process function which I've played with a little bit to see what comes through the options param -- however that appears (I think) to make the chunking calculations my responsibility. My original thought was to manipulate the `options.chunkServer.url` to include the query params I need but I don't believe this processes individual chunks.

In case it makes a difference, this is being done in React using the [react-filepond package](https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond).

Comment: I think you're going to have to use a custom processing method, no way around that at this point. I'd advise to use the FilePond code you can find in the repository and copy paste some of it to your method.

Answer (score 0):

I made and implementation in Laravel 6 using Traits and some "bad practices" (I didn't have time because ... release in prod) to join chunks into a file

Basically:

1. post to get unique id folder to storage
2. get chunks and join together
3. profit!

Here's the full code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Traits\Upload;

use Closure;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

trait Uploadeable
{
   public function uploadFileInStorage(Request $request, Closure $closure)
   {
       // get the nex offset for next chunk send
       if (($request->isMethod('options') || $request->isMethod('head')) && $request->has('patch')) {

           //get the temp dir
           $dir = $request->patch . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

           // reead all chunks in directory
           $patch = collect(Storage::files($dir))
               ->sortBy(function ($file) {
                   return Storage::lastModified($file);
               });

           // read offsets for calculate
           $offsets = array();
           $size = 0;
           $last_offset = 0;
           foreach ($patch as $filename) {
               $size = Storage::size($filename);

               list($dir, $offset) = explode('file.patch.', $filename, 2);

               array_push($offsets, $offset);

               if ($offset > 0 && !in_array($offset - $size, $offsets)) {
                   $last_offset = $offset - $size;
                   break;
               }

               // last offset is at least next offset
               $last_offset = $offset + $size;
           }
           // return offset
           return response($last_offset, 200)
               ->header('Upload-Offset', $last_offset);
       }

       // chunks
       if ($request->isMethod('patch') && $request->has('patch')) {
           // get the temp dir
           $dir = $request->patch . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

           // read headers
           $offset = $request->header('upload-offset');
           $length = $request->header('upload-length');

           // should be numeric values, else exit
           if (!is_numeric($offset) || !is_numeric($length)) {
               return response('', 400);
           }

           // get the file name
           $name = $request->header('Upload-Name');

           // sleep server for get a diference between file created to sort
           usleep(500000);

           // storage the chunk with name + offset
           Storage::put($dir . 'file.patch.' . $offset, $request->getContent());

           // calculate total size of patches
           $size = 0;
           $patch = Storage::files($dir);
           foreach ($patch as $filename) {
               $size += Storage::size($filename);
           }

           // make the final file
           if ($size == $length) {
               // read all chunks in directory
               $files = collect(Storage::files($dir))
                   ->sortBy(function ($file) {
                       return Storage::lastModified($file);
                   });

               // create output file
               //Log::info(storage_path('app'));
               $new_file_name = $final_name = trim(storage_path('app') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir . $name);
               $file_handle = fopen($new_file_name, 'w');

               // write patches to file
               foreach ($files as $filename) {
                   // get offset from filename
                   list($dir, $offset) = explode('.patch.', $filename, 2);

                   // read chunk
                   $patch_handle = fopen(storage_path('app') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . trim($filename), 'r');
                   $patch_contents = fread($patch_handle, filesize(storage_path('app') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . trim($filename)));
                   fclose($patch_handle);

                   // apply patch
                   fseek($file_handle, $offset);
                   fwrite($file_handle, $patch_contents);
               }

               // done with file
               fclose($file_handle);

               // file permission (prefered 0755)
               chmod($final_name, 0777);

               // remove patches
               foreach ($patch as $filename) {
                   $new_file_name = storage_path('app') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . trim($filename);
                   unlink($new_file_name);
               }
               
               // simple class (no time to explain)
               $file = new UploadedFile(
                   $final_name,
                   basename($final_name),
                   mime_content_type($final_name),
                   filesize($final_name),
                   false
               );

               $dir = $request->patch . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

               $object = new \stdClass();
               $object->full_path = (string)$file->getPathname();
               $object->directory = (string)($dir);
               $object->path = (string)($dir . basename($final_name));
               $object->name = (string)$file->getClientOriginalName();
               $object->mime_type = (string)$file->getClientMimeType();
               $object->extension = (string)$file->getExtension();
               $object->size = (string)$this->formatSizeUnits($file->getSize());

               // exec closure
               $closure($file, (object)$object, $request);
           }

           // response
           return response()->json([
               'message' => 'Archivo subido correctamente.',
               'filename' => $name
           ], 200);
       }

       // get dir unique id folder temp
       if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
           $faker = Faker::create();
           $unique_id = $faker->uuid . '-' . time();
           $unique_folder_path = $unique_id;

           // create directory
           Storage::makeDirectory($unique_folder_path);

           // permisos directorio
           chmod(storage_path('app') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $unique_folder_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 0777);

           // response with folder
           return response($unique_id, 200)
               ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
       }
   }

   private function formatSizeUnits($bytes)
   {
       if ($bytes >= 1073741824) {
           $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1073741824, 2) . ' GB';
       } elseif ($bytes >= 1048576) {
           $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
       } elseif ($bytes >= 1024) {
           $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1024, 2) . ' KB';
       } elseif ($bytes > 1) {
           $bytes = $bytes . ' bytes';
       } elseif ($bytes == 1) {
           $bytes = $bytes . ' byte';
       } else {
           $bytes = '0 bytes';
       }

       return $bytes;
   }
}
´´´
```